# Leading number on variable name throws error

Tags: jquery, error-handling

I am declaring a variable that has a dynamic name.

```
var 8inuf3k9r2ggp914zey8hn6vgwky3aqalr4zi6a01yx4x8cdv4eqlby9i6a9v9j4 = pusher.subscribe('channel');
```

Chrome throws an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number".

I am sure that the issue is that some of my employee ids lead with a number.  Any employee id that I have that starts with alpha has no issue.  I am sure there is a simple solution but I am having trouble googling the right thing.  I will post actual code if needed but the issue is pretty straight forward.

The Long var name is the dynamic employee number.

Comment: You can't start an identifier with a number.

Comment: I get that.  but how can i adjust the name to maybe prefix with something.  I can't change my empid's

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can't use a number to lead a variable name.

You could possibly use an associative array:

```
var employee = [];
employee["8inuf3k9r2ggp914zey8hn6vgwky3aqalr4zi6a01yx4x8cdv4eqlby9i6a9v9j4"] = pusher.subscribe('channel');
```

Comment: that sounds like it is going down the right path.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As [Andrew Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647260/andrew-li) said, you cannot start an identifier (in your case, a varible name) with a number.

If you really want to do this, use :

```
window[employee_id] = 'data';
console.log(window[employee_id]);
```

Note that this is very bad practice to use an User Input as a variable name, for security reasons. Consider using an array instead.